# How to get a reasonably well working generator class template in C++20?

Tags: c++, generator, c++20

I'm just a simple coder who used Python a lot and got addicted to its generators. As far as I understand the current situation, they can be cleanly implemented in C++20 with coroutines, however, at least until C++23, it's not a trivial task since one needs to write a generator class (template). How do I get one that

1. Runs reasonably fast (at least not slower than the good old [generators hack with macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)#C++))
2. I can use ranged-based `for`, the ranges library and some equivalent of Python's `next` on it. It would also be great if there was a method to test whether the generator is exhausted.
3. When (if?) an equivalent is added to the standard library, I (with high probability) won't need to change my code too much

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Trying to implement various features and patterns in a language can be fun and educating. For serious code though try to adapt yourself to the language idioms and patterns instead of trying to adapt the language to your habbits.

Comment: @bolov do you have any tips for adapting to the lack of generators beyond writing it inline every time? For example in the case of generating all strings of length $n$ over an alphabet.

Comment: Can this question be reopened? I edited it to be merely about a "good" solution instead of the "best" one, and I think that the criteria I gave are clear.

Comment: @acupoftea: You shouldn't try so hard to make one language behave like another. Use the idioms present in the new language; don't try to carry over idioms from your old one.

Comment: @NicolBolas see my response to user bolov above.

Comment: @acupoftea: You "adapt" by learning C++ idioms. And those idioms may be a lot less friendly and/or a lot more wordy than what you're used to. And some of them may just require "writing it inline every time".

Comment: @NicolBolas: One of the reasons coroutines were introduced was to implement generators (thus the `co_yield` keyword).  Maybe it was “making C++ behave like Python” before, but that’s not true anymore (even if the set of problems for which they are the most appropriate solution might differ between the two).

Comment: If you are not reluctant to using external libs while waiting until 2023, try [libcoro](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro)

Comment: @nop666 I figured out how to use some other library but still don't know how to have point 2 from my list above.

Comment: Rather than "some equivalent of Python's `next`" you should use `operator++` and `operator==` applied to `iterator`s. The generator is exhausted once your iterator is equal to `end`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, [libcoro](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro) provides a higher level of abstraction and might solve some of your issues.

For point2, if you really need a public method that tells you the generator is exhausted, I guess enhancing libcoro generator would make it somehow easy. Here is a (not tested) possible sample. But is checking against generator.end() a problem for you?

```
namespace libcoro {
    template<typename T>
    class [[nodiscard]] generator
    {
    public:

    using reference_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_reference_v<T>, T, T&>;

    //.. libcoro stuff

    // ADDED
    bool done() const {
      m_coroutine.done();
    }

    reference_type value() const {
      return m_coroutine.promise().value();
    }

    void resume() {
      m_coroutine.resume();
    }

    // ...
};
```

}

Then you can do:

```
while (true) {
        gen.resume();
        if(gen.done()) {
            std::cout << "this is the end!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "new value: " << gen.value() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Maybe by "method" I didn't necessarily mean the technical sense :)

Comment: @acupoftea Yes, I got it, don't worry. The "proposed method" extends the API by adding new public member functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some reasonably fast generator [implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/4sbYGa) which prefers a std implementation if available (like in MSVC):

In my real code it is splitted in multiple files, but to show it here I merged it...

It works with all major comilers (gcc, clang, msvc).

```
//------------------
//general coroutine support
//------------------
#if defined(__clang__)
    //see: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/502513/unable-to-use-clang-cl-coroutines-due-to-unresolve.html
    namespace std {
        namespace experimental {
            inline namespace coroutines_v1 {

                template <typename R, typename...>
                struct coroutine_traits {
                    using promise_type = typename R::promise_type;
                };

                template <typename Promise = void> 
                struct coroutine_handle;

                template <> struct coroutine_handle<void> {
                    static coroutine_handle from_address(void* addr) noexcept {
                        coroutine_handle me;
                        me.ptr = addr;
                        return me;
                    }
                    void operator()() { resume(); }
                    void* address() const { return ptr; }
                    void resume() const { __builtin_coro_resume(ptr); }
                    void destroy() const { __builtin_coro_destroy(ptr); }
                    bool done() const { return __builtin_coro_done(ptr); }
                    coroutine_handle& operator=(decltype(nullptr)) {
                        ptr = nullptr;
                        return *this;
                    }
                    coroutine_handle(decltype(nullptr)) : ptr(nullptr) {}
                    coroutine_handle() : ptr(nullptr) {}
                    //  void reset() { ptr = nullptr; } // add to P0057?
                    explicit operator bool() const { return ptr; }

                protected:
                    void* ptr;
                };

                template <typename Promise> 
                struct coroutine_handle : coroutine_handle<> {
                    using coroutine_handle<>::operator=;
                    using coroutine_handle<>::coroutine_handle;

                    static coroutine_handle from_address(void* addr) noexcept {
                        coroutine_handle me;
                        me.ptr = addr;
                        return me;
                    }

                    Promise& promise() const {
                        return *reinterpret_cast<Promise*>(
                            __builtin_coro_promise(ptr, alignof(Promise), false));
                    }
                    static coroutine_handle from_promise(Promise& promise) {
                        coroutine_handle p;
                        p.ptr = __builtin_coro_promise(&promise, alignof(Promise), true);
                        return p;
                    }
                };

                template <typename _PromiseT>
                bool operator==(coroutine_handle<_PromiseT> const& _Left,
                    coroutine_handle<_PromiseT> const& _Right) noexcept
                {
                    return _Left.address() == _Right.address();
                }

                template <typename _PromiseT>
                bool operator!=(coroutine_handle<_PromiseT> const& _Left,
                    coroutine_handle<_PromiseT> const& _Right) noexcept
                {
                    return !(_Left == _Right);
                }

                struct suspend_always {
                    bool await_ready() noexcept { return false; }
                    void await_suspend(coroutine_handle<>) noexcept {}
                    void await_resume() noexcept {}
                };
                struct suspend_never {
                    bool await_ready() noexcept { return true; }
                    void await_suspend(coroutine_handle<>) noexcept {}
                    void await_resume() noexcept {}
                };
            }
        }
    }
    #define NATIVE_COROUTINE_IMPL_NS std::experimental
#elif __has_include(<coroutine>)
    #include <coroutine>
    #define NATIVE_COROUTINE_IMPL_NS std    
#elif __has_include(<experimental/coroutine>)
    #include <experimental/coroutine>
    #define NATIVE_COROUTINE_IMPL_NS std::experimental
#endif

//------------------
//Generator defintion
//-----------------

#if __has_include(<generator>)
    #include <generator>
    namespace CORE_NATIVE_NS
    {
        template<typename T>
        using YieldEnum = std::generator<T>;
    }
#elif __has_include(<experimental/generator>) && !defined(__clang__)
    #include <experimental/generator>
    namespace CORE_NATIVE_NS
    {
        template<typename T>
        using YieldEnum = std::experimental::generator<T>;
    }
#else
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <exception>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

namespace CORE_NATIVE_NS
{
    template<typename T>
    class generator;

    namespace detail
    {
        template<typename T>
        class generator_promise
        {
        public:
            using value_type = std::remove_reference_t<T>;
            using reference_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_reference_v<T>, T, T&>;
            using pointer_type = value_type*;

            generator_promise() = default;

            generator<T> get_return_object() noexcept;

            constexpr NATIVE_COROUTINE_IMPL_NS::suspend_always initial_suspend() const noexcept 
            { return {}; }
            constexpr NATIVE_COROUTINE_IMPL_NS::suspend_always final_suspend() const noexcept
            { return {}; }

            template<
                typename U = T,
                std::enable_if_t<!std::is_rvalue_reference<U>::value, int> = 0
            >
            NATIVE_COROUTINE_IMPL_NS::suspend_always yield_value(std::remove_reference_t<T>& value) noexcept
            {
                m_value = std::addressof(value);
                return {};
            }

            NATIVE_COROUTINE_IMPL_NS::suspend_always yield_value(std::remove_reference_t<T>&& value) noexcept
            {
                m_value = std::addressof(value);
                return {};
            }

            void unhandled_exception() noexcept
            {
                m_exception = std::current_exception();
            }

            void return_void() const noexcept
            {
            }

            reference_type value() const noexcept
            {
                return static_cast<reference_type>(*m_value);
            }

            // Don't allow any use of 'co_await' inside the generator coroutine.
            template<typename U>
            NATIVE_COROUTINE_IMPL_NS::suspend_never await_transform(U&& value) = delete;

            void rethrow_if_exception()
            {
                if (m_exception)
                {
                    std::rethrow_exception(m_exception);
                }
            }
        private:
            pointer_type m_value;
            std::exception_ptr m_exception;
        };

        struct generator_sentinel {};

        template<typename T>
        class generator_iterator
        {
            using coroutine_handle = NATIVE_COROUTINE_IMPL_NS::coroutine_handle<generator_promise<T>>;
        public:

            using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
            // What type should we use for counting elements of a potentially infinite sequence?
            using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
            using value_type = typename generator_promise<T>::value_type;
            using reference = typename generator_promise<T>::reference_type;
            using pointer = typename generator_promise<T>::pointer_type;

            // Iterator needs to be default-constructible to satisfy the Range concept.
            generator_iterator() noexcept
                : m_coroutine(nullptr)
            {}

            explicit generator_iterator(coroutine_handle coroutine) noexcept
                : m_coroutine(coroutine)
            {}

            friend bool operator==(const generator_iterator& it, generator_sentinel) noexcept
            {
                return !it.m_coroutine || it.m_coroutine.done();
            }

            friend bool operator!=(const generator_iterator& it, generator_sentinel s) noexcept
            {
                return !(it == s);
            }

            friend bool operator==(generator_sentinel s, const generator_iterator& it) noexcept
            {
                return (it == s);
            }

            friend bool operator!=(generator_sentinel s, const generator_iterator& it) noexcept
            {
                return it != s;
            }

            generator_iterator& operator++()
            {
                m_coroutine.resume();
                if (m_coroutine.done())
                {
                    m_coroutine.promise().rethrow_if_exception();
                }

                return *this;
            }

            // Need to provide post-increment operator to implement the 'Range' concept.
            void operator++(int)
            {
                (void)operator++();
            }

            void next(){
                (void)operator++();
            }

            reference operator*() const noexcept
            {
                return m_coroutine.promise().value();
            }

            pointer operator->() const noexcept
            {
                return std::addressof(operator*());
            }

        private:
            coroutine_handle m_coroutine;
        };
    }

    template<typename T>
    class [[nodiscard]] generator
    {
    public:

        using promise_type = detail::generator_promise<T>;
        using iterator = detail::generator_iterator<T>;

        generator() noexcept
            : m_coroutine(nullptr)
        {}

        generator(generator&& other) noexcept
            : m_coroutine(other.m_coroutine)
        {
            other.m_coroutine = nullptr;
        }

        generator(const generator& other) = delete;

        ~generator()
        {
            if (m_coroutine)
            {
                m_coroutine.destroy();
            }
        }

        generator& operator=(generator other) noexcept
        {
            swap(other);
            return *this;
        }

        iterator begin()
        {
            if (m_coroutine)
            {
                m_coroutine.resume();
                if (m_coroutine.done())
                {
                    m_coroutine.promise().rethrow_if_exception();
                }
            }

            return iterator{ m_coroutine };
        }

        detail::generator_sentinel end() noexcept
        {
            return detail::generator_sentinel{};
        }

        void swap(generator& other) noexcept
        {
            std::swap(m_coroutine, other.m_coroutine);
        }

    private:

        friend class detail::generator_promise<T>;

        explicit generator(NATIVE_COROUTINE_IMPL_NS::coroutine_handle<promise_type> coroutine) noexcept
            : m_coroutine(coroutine)
        {}

        NATIVE_COROUTINE_IMPL_NS::coroutine_handle<promise_type> m_coroutine;

    };

    template<typename T>
    void swap(generator<T>& a, generator<T>& b)
    {
        a.swap(b);
    }

    namespace detail
    {
        template<typename T>
        generator<T> generator_promise<T>::get_return_object() noexcept
        {
            using coroutine_handle = NATIVE_COROUTINE_IMPL_NS::coroutine_handle<generator_promise<T>>;
            return generator<T>{ coroutine_handle::from_promise(*this) };
        }
    }

    template<typename FUNC, typename T>
    generator<std::invoke_result_t<FUNC&, typename generator<T>::iterator::reference>> fmap(FUNC func, generator<T> source)
    {
        for (auto&& value : source)
        {
            co_yield std::invoke(func, static_cast<decltype(value)>(value));
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    using YieldEnum = CORE_NATIVE_NS::generator<T>;
}
#endif


inline CORE_NATIVE_NS::YieldEnum<int> GetNumbers() noexcept
{
    for(int i=0; i<= 10; ++i){
        co_yield 10;
    }
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(auto x : GetNumbers()){
        sum += x;
    }
    std::cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```